# how to get google analytics report from website launch date

Tags: google-analytics

Has anyone know how to get google analytics report from website launch's date? I'm start using the google analytics from July 25 and the analytics report collecting from July 25 too. But the website was launch from 2 years ago. So, I want to see the analytics report about 2 years ago. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't.  Google collects from the day the tracking code was installed. Your best change at this point is to see if your server kept its log files for the last two years (possible, but not likely) and use something like webalyzer to to some log file analysis. This will give you less information than a GA report would, but you will at least get something.